# Minor log y ticks dissapear randomly

Tags: pgfplots, ticks

Does anybody know how to force y log minor ticks? In the following example, the ticks do show up:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{semilogyaxis}[log base y={10}]
      \addplot {2^x}; 
    \end{semilogyaxis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But if I want to plot `10^x`, the ticks disappear:

[image]

Or when I change to `log base y={11}`, the ticks also disappear:

[image]

Using `yminorticks=true` doesn't work. Does anybody know how to get the y log minor ticks back in these cases?

Comment: According to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/207820/194703) the minor ticks are only set if "if the distance between consecutive major ticks is exactly one logarithmic unit". So if you add `try min ticks log=15` the minor ticks will appear but the axis will become crowded. Alternatively you can add them by hand. (Of course there might be a better solution...)

Comment: Thank you. Setting `max space between ticks=1` does work to resolve first problem. What to do if `log base y={11}` is involved?

Comment: Good question. It does not seem to be supported out of the box (or I am missing something).

Comment: The key `log identify minor tick positions` identifies tick labels at positions `..., 1*10, 2*10, 3*10, 4*10, 5*10, 6*10, 7*10, 8*10, 9*10, 1*10^2, ...`. This scheme does not make sense any more if you use a base of 11 (which is why the minor ticks are not drawn at all, since there will be a different number of them between two major ticks).

Comment: @RuixiZhang, I disagree with the scheme not making sense if there are 11 minor ticks (at the positions `1*11, 2*11, ..., 10*11`).

Comment: I probably didn’t express my idea clearly. I agree that `1*11, 2*11, ..., 10*11` followed by `11*11, ...` makes sense, but my point is that in base 11 you have 10 minor ticks between 2 major ticks. While in base 10, you have only 9 minor ticks in between. I suspect `pgfplots` “hardcoded” 9 minor ticks in its library, so it makes no sense if the number of minor ticks changes from 9 to 10 (so they are not drawn). I also didn’t find how to set minor ticks in the manual.